# Why False && {False, False} does not preserve list structure?

Tags: list-manipulation, boolean-computation

I am on Mathematica 12.1.1.0 trying to perform a boolean operation over every element of a list, but preserving the list structure.

When I run

`True && {True, True}`

the result is

> {True, True}

However, if I run

`False && {False, False}`

the result is

> False

i.e., the list structure disappears.

What is the reason? And what is the best way to combine a single boolean condition with every element of a list, preserving the list structure?

Comment: `Map`ping (or `/@`) `True` or `False` over a list of Boolean values while preserving list structure would be done like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Vz07.png).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Welcome to MMA SE! The reason is that `And` (`&&`) is short-circuited. This means that as soon as an argument is `False` (starting from the left), the whole thing immediately evaluates to `False`. So `False && expr` is `False` for any `expr`.

The opposite behavior occurs when the first argument is `True`: `True && expr` gives `expr` for any `expr`. If the first argument is `True`, then you still need to check the next arguments. But you know that whatever the output of `And` is, it will be given by those next arguments; so you can disregard the initial `True`. And from the docs:

> `And` gives symbolic results when necessary, removing initial arguments that are `True`.

So `&&` is not actually preserving the list structure in the first case; it's just returning the second argument.

To preserve the list structure, one solution is to use `Map` to map a function over a list, for which there is the syntactic sugar `/@`. We can map the anonymous functions `True && # &` and `False && # &` over the list:

```
True && # & /@ {False, True}

False && # & /@ {False, True}
```

However, depending on your application, you might want to do things slightly differently. Defining a symbol to "mean" `And` but have the attribute `Listable` comes to mind, for example (since the attribute gets applied before the definition does):

```
myAnd[args___] := And[args]
SetAttributes[myAnd, Listable]

myAnd[True, {False, True}]
myAnd[False, {False, True}]
```

The Help docs for `Function` and `Map` likely link to other things you might find useful at the bottom!